# How to Full Screen CSS of a child element ignoring father element style

Tags: css, fullscreen

I have a div with width 200px, and a child-div with width 100%

```
<div id="header">
   <br>
   <br>
   <div id="headerContent">
       <h1>Header text</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>

#header{width:100px; background: blue; padding: 10px 0;}
#headerContent{margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;background:red}
```

I want make the headerContent as to fullscreen width

Comment: if you don't want the child to be constrained to the parent size, is there a reason why it has to be inside the other element?

Comment: @Jesse is right. You may try but not advisable at all. To force it you can set the header `position:absolute;` . and ruin the structure.

Comment: As the others mentioned, this is not a really good idea. If the HTML structure is up to you, either make it so that headerContent isn't a child of header. Or just make header have a width of 100%